# MATLAB: variable progress is uninitialized temporary not reduction

Tags: matlab, loops, parallel-processing, parfor

In a simple progress indicator, I update how much percent the loop has gone forward:

```
progress=0;
N=10;

for k=1:N
    % ....
    progress=progress+1;
    disp(sprintf('progress %d%%',progress/N*100));
end
```

And the output:

> progress 10%
>
> progress 20%
>
> progress 30%
>
> progress 40%
>
> progress 50%
>
> progress 60%
>
> progress 70%
>
> progress 80%
>
> progress 90%
>
> progress 100%

However, when I try to change the `for` loop into `parfor` (parallel loop), I face with an error

```
progress=0;
N=10;

parfor k=1:N
    % ....
    progress=progress+1;
    disp(sprintf('progress %d%%',progress/N*100));
end
```

> Error using test (line 4)
>
> Error: The variable progress is perhaps intended as a reduction
>   variable, but is actually an uninitialized temporary.
>
> See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Temporary Variables Intended as
>   Reduction Variables".

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

A *reduction variable* inside `parfor` cannot be read during the loop execution. Remember that all the iterations of the loop are conceptually happening simultaneously. MATLAB knows how to transform the expression

```
progress = progress + 1;
```

into something meaningful because of the precise form of that expression (i.e. it recognises the *associative* nature of the operation). There is no communication possible among the workers executing the body of the `parfor` loop, so there is no way to determine the overall value of `progress` until the loop has completed.

If you want to display progress in this way, you might wish to investigate using [`parfeval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html) which allows you to submit work asynchronously to the workers, and monitor overall progress back at the client. Here's an example [in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/examples/parfeval-blackjack.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. could you please fit the proposed method into the code above? (I have no idea how to use that)

Comment: @zahmati did you look at the example I linked to in the documentation? That shows you how to create multiple `parallel.Future` objects by calling `parfeval` to execute the body of the loop. Back at the client, you call `fetchNext` in a loop, and each time that returns, you know another `Future` has completed, so you can display progress.